# Change output device for pulseaudio A2DP sink

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth

I just configured my desktop computer to be a bluetooth A2DP sink.

When I connect a smartphone to it via bluetooth, it appears as a hardware input device, so that I am unable to change the playback device (which is currently my internal soundcard instead of the USB headset I would like).

How can I change the playback device that acts as a sink for the A2DP hardware input device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually discovered a solution on my own while writing this (not that I didn't search).

It is possible to change the sink of a hardware input device directly via `pavucontrol`, thereby controlling the "echo" or feedback of the said recording device/microphone.

However, the controls to do so were hidden by default. In the playback tab, I had to select "All streams" instead of "Applications": that displayed the stream in the window, which I could then reassign to another device.

This solves my current problem, but doesn't completely satisfy me, as it doesn't seem to allow this for regular microphones, and I do not know how to do it via `pactl`.